# Is param in a tab possible?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple p:tabView (non-Ajax) and a couple of p:tab on it. Now when I click on a p:tab I would like to achieve that the url changes with a new GET-parameter. So I thought putting f:param into p:tab, but this does not seem to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Are f:param in p:tab possible? Or can somebody confirm that f:param generally is not possible for GET-parameter within a p:tabView?

A part of my facelet:

```
<p:tabView cache="false" effect="fade">
    <p:tab title="Home">
        <f:param name="main" value="home" />
        <h:outputText value="#{homeBean.report}" escape="false"/>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: No you can't do that; Do you just want to be able to navigate to specific tabs?

Comment: Sad! :( Yep, it is the tabs I am interested in. But I need the GET functionality.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the GET functionality"? What use-case are you expecting with a GET?